# Is there a change between Hibernate 4.3.x and 4.2.x in how they hydrate abstract implemented classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We recently upgraded from Hibernate 4.2.12 to 4.3.5, and after we upgraded getting an abstract class started to fail with this error:

`Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.siftit.domain.core.user.User with id 138`

The user actually exists, and like I said this works in 4.2.12, but once we upgrade to 4.3.5 it fails, but if we change the user to be a specific type (i.e. SomeUser) then the get works.

We are using:

Spring: 4.0.3.RELEASE

Spring Data: 1.5.1.RELEASE

JPA: 1.2

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class User extends AbstractEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name="someUser")
public class SomeUser extends User {
}

@Entity
@Table(name="someClass")
public class SomeClass extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    User user;

   public User getUser(){ return user;} //This is really a restaurant user that should fill this and if we map it as a restaurant user, everything works, but if we keep it mapped as user it fails.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I bumped into the same problem while upgrading from 4.2.7 to 4.3.5. Using `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` instead of `InheritanceType.JOINED` fixed the problem for me.